# Moving months to quarter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table with monthly data. Every month a new month is added and the oldest is dropped. It covers 24 months. I now need a view of this data on a quarterly base, showing only full quarters per year (in a seperate table). Because of the moving nature of the monthly data i have no idea how to do this and would appreciate your help. The headers for the columns are formatted as dates: 2012/sep.

[image]

Above a small sample from the monthly view. So for 1st row the quarters would be: 2012 Q1 to Q3. for the second row only 2012 Q1 and Q2. 2011/dec is only a partial so not visible in quarter view, same for 2012/oct and missing data data in row 2.

[image]

And this is what the (as a result also moving) quarterlies would look like. At most 8 full Q's are possible.
3 months to a quarter.

Comment: please add some screenshots of _what I have_ and _what I want_, this is the easiest way to get your point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure about how it should look like when it is ready, but this formula might help you to get there:

```
="Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(P3)/3,0)
```

That way you can determine, which quarter a date is in.

Because it is based on the date, it is dynamic, and as the dates move, the quartes move accordingly. So you should have it easy.

*Edit*

Ah ok, getting a picture of it. You will have to use the `ROUNDUP` part in a `SUBTOTAL` with an `OFFSET`, that way you could slide the subtotal through your data.

You could also use `SUMIF`, when you provide a row with the current quarter for each date.

Ans this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175801/find-and-sort-same-months-name-as-single-in-microsoft-excel-2007/13176826#13176826 might inspire your solutions, because it is a quite equal situation.

Comment: I (think I) understand the offset in the subtotal. but i cant figure out how to get the first reference in the subtotal. =SUBTOTAL(9,V5,OFFSET(V5,0,1),OFFSET(V5,0,2)). How do i find V5 using the roundup part.